# How to use Python's random number generator with a local seed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

Python's random seems are global, so modules changing it will effect each other.

While there are of course many 3rd party modules, is there a way using Python's standard library to have a random number local to a context.

(without using `random.get/setstate` which may be problematic when mixing code from different modules).

Something like...

```
r = random.context(seed=42)
number = r.randint(10, 20)
```

Where each module can use its own random context.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

> The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a hidden instance of the `random.Random` class. You can instantiate your own instances of `Random` to get generators that don’t share state.

Make your own `random.Random` instance and use that.

```
rng = random.Random(42)
number = rng.randint(10, 20)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was expecting to see this documented more prominently, but its only referenced as plain-text in the middle of a paragraph. - https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html - with no heading or example code.

Comment: I came here to see an example, since it wasn't in the doc. Thanks.