# Can I create a local numpy random seed?

Tags: python, numpy, random, scope

There is a function, `foo`, that uses the `np.random` functionality.
I want to control the seed that `foo` uses, but without actually changing the function itself.
How do I do this?

Essentially I want something like this:

```
bar() # should have normal seed
with np.random.seed(0): # Doesn't work
    foo()
bar() # should have normal seed
```

---

Solutions like 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355985/how-to-use-pythons-random-number-generator-with-a-local-seed):

```
rng = random.Random(42)
number = rng.randint(10, 20)
```

doesn't work in this case, as I don't have access to the inner workings of `foo` (or am I missing something??).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Python's random number generator with a local seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355985/how-to-use-pythons-random-number-generator-with-a-local-seed)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate, as `rng = random.Random(42); number = rng.randint(10, 20)` solution doesn't work in this case, as I don't have access to the inner workings of `foo`.

Comment: I didn't read that properly then, sorry. My guess then would be to start a new process with a seed. Let me try some stuff.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could keep the global random state in a temporary variable and reset it once your function is done:

```
import contextlib
import numpy as np

@contextlib.contextmanager
def temp_seed(seed):
    state = np.random.get_state()
    np.random.seed(seed)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        np.random.set_state(state)
```

Demo:

```
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> np.random.randn(3)
array([1.76405235, 0.40015721, 0.97873798])
>>> np.random.randn(3)
array([ 2.2408932 ,  1.86755799, -0.97727788])

>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> np.random.randn(3)
array([1.76405235, 0.40015721, 0.97873798])
>>> with temp_seed(5):
...     np.random.randn(3)                                                                                        
array([ 0.44122749, -0.33087015,  2.43077119])
>>> np.random.randn(3)
array([ 2.2408932 ,  1.86755799, -0.97727788])
```

Comment: Ah nice.. `get`/`set_state` :) Which of course has the benefit that the global state remains invariant.

Comment: You probably want a `try` / `finally` in there, so that the random state gets restored even if there's an exception raised in the `with` block that's using this context manager.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Fixed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the idea is that calls to `bar()` should when given a starting seed always see the same sequence of random numbers; regardless of how many calls to `foo()`are inserted in-between.

We can do this by creating a random seed from the random state that we use to re-seed when the temporary seeded state is done. This can be wrapped in a context manager:

```
import numpy as np

class temporary_seed:
    def __init__(self, seed):
        self.seed = seed
        self.backup = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.backup = np.random.randint(2**32-1, dtype=np.uint32)
        np.random.seed(self.seed)

    def __exit__(self, *_):
        np.random.seed(self.backup)
```

Let's try this with

```
def bar():
    print('bar:', np.random.randint(10))

def foo():
    print('foo:', np.random.randint(10))

np.random.seed(999)

bar()  # bar: 0
with temporary_seed(42):
    foo()  # foo: 6
    foo()  # foo: 3
bar()  # bar: 9
```

So we get bar-sequence [0, 9] and foo-sequence [6, 3].

We try again without re-seeding globally:

```
bar()  # bar: 1
with temporary_seed(42):
    foo()  # foo: 6
    foo()  # foo: 3
bar()  # bar: 2
```

New bar-sequence [1, 2] and same foo-sequence again [6, 3].

Once again with same global seed, but a different seed for foo:

```
np.random.seed(999)

bar()  # bar: 0
with temporary_seed(0):
    foo()  # foo: 5
bar()  # bar: 9
```

This time we get the first bar-sequence again [0, 9] and a different foo. Nice!

So where is the catch? By entering and leaving the temorary seed part we change the random state. We do so deterministically and the results are repeatable, but if we get a different sequence if we don't call enter `temorary_seed`:

```
np.random.seed(999)

bar()  # bar: 0
bar()  # bar: 5
```

bar-sequence [0, 5] instead of [0, 9]. If you can live with that limitation this approach should work.

Comment: I don't understand `self.backup = np.random.randint(2**32-1, dtype=np.uint32)`. Can you explain it?

Comment: @Toke Faurby It creates a full-range integer random number to be used as the seed when leaving the context.