# How to cancel the effect of numpy seed()?

Tags: python, numpy, random-seed

I would like to use np.random.seed() in the first part of my program and cancel it in the second part. 
Again,

- in the first part of my python file, I want the same random numbers to be generated at each execution
- in the second part , I want different random numbers to be generated at each execution

Comment: There is no such thing as cancelling a seed. It just amounts to setting a different seed, based on some random-ish conditions, like milliseconds from epoch.

Comment: Just pass None, or don't pass anything at all: `np.random.seed()`

Comment: I tried and the seed deletes itself after a random number generation.

Comment: Thanks ayhan. It works

Comment: OP won't need this but it is actually possible to ["cancel"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49557127/7207392) setting a seed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the first part initialize the seed with a constant, e.g. 0:

```
numpy.random.seed(0)
```

In the second part initialize the seed with time:

```
import time
t = 1000 * time.time() # current time in milliseconds
np.random.seed(int(t) % 2**32)
```

(the seed must be between 0 and and 2**32 - 1)

Note: you obtain a similar effect by calling `np.random.seed()` with no arguments, i.e. a new (pseudo)-unpredictable sequence.

Each time you initialize the seed with the same constant, you get the same sequence of numbers:

```
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(10)]
[5, 0, 3, 3, 7, 9, 3, 5, 2, 4]
>>> [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(10)]
[7, 6, 8, 8, 1, 6, 7, 7, 8, 1]
>>> np.random.seed(0)
>>> [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(10)]
[5, 0, 3, 3, 7, 9, 3, 5, 2, 4]
```

Hence initalizing with the current number of milliseconds gives you some pseudo-random sequence.

Comment: Thanks to you and to ayhan