# How to specify a random seed while using Python's numpy random choice?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, random

I have a list of four strings. Then in a Pandas dataframe I want to create a variable randomly selecting a value from this list and assign into each row. I am using numpy's random choice, but reading their documentation, there is no seed option. How can I specify the random seed to the random assignment so every time the random assignment will be the same?

```
service_code_options = ['899.59O', '12.42R', '13.59P', '204.68L']
df['SERVICE_CODE'] = [np.random.choice(service_code_options ) for i in df.index]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need define it before by [`numpy.random.seed`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html), also list comprehension is not necessary, because is possible use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with parameter `size`:

```
np.random.seed(123)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10)})

service_code_options = ['899.59O', '12.42R', '13.59P', '204.68L']
df['SERVICE_CODE'] = np.random.choice(service_code_options, size=len(df))
print (df)
   a SERVICE_CODE
0  0       13.59P
1  1       12.42R
2  2       13.59P
3  3       13.59P
4  4      899.59O
5  5       13.59P
6  6       13.59P
7  7       12.42R
8  8      204.68L
9  9       13.59P
```

Comment: Question, "np.random.seed(123)" does it apply to all the following codes that call for random function from numpy. If so, is there a way to terminate it, and say, if I want to make another variable using a different seed, do I declare another "np.random.seed(897)" to affect the subsequent codes?

Comment: Got the ans here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966770/how-to-cancel-the-effect-of-numpy-seed. Thanks.

Comment: @KubiK888 - So sorry, I was offline.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation [`numpy.random.seed`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html)

```
np.random.seed(this_is_my_seed)
```

That could be an integer or a list of integers

```
np.random.seed(300)
```

Or

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
```

#### Example

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])

service_code_options = ['899.59O', '12.42R', '13.59P', '204.68L']
np.random.choice(service_code_options, 3)

array(['899.59O', '204.68L', '13.59P'], dtype='<U7')
```

Notice that I passed a `3` to the `choice` function to specify the size of the array.

[`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

Comment: What would a list of integers do? Use the n-th element as seed after n random() calls?

Comment: Nothing special except to provide a different seed

Comment: Yes but is the list parsed in order?

Comment: No, the whole list is just a thing that provides a starting point for the randomization.

Answer (score 3):

According to the notes of [`numpy.random.seed`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) in numpy v1.2.4:

> Best practice is to use a dedicated **Generator** instance rather than the random variate generation methods exposed directly in the random module.

Such a **Generator** is constructed using [`np.random.default_rng`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.default_rng).

Thus, instead of `np.random.seed`, the current best practice is to use a `np.random.default_rng` with a seed to construct a **Generator**, which can be further used for reproducible results.

Combining [jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52991726/7789963) and the current best practice, we have:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=121)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(10)})

service_code_options = ['899.59O', '12.42R', '13.59P', '204.68L']
df['SERVICE_CODE'] = rng.choice(service_code_options, size=len(df))

print(df)
```

```
   a SERVICE_CODE
0  0       12.42R
1  1       13.59P
2  2       12.42R
3  3       12.42R
4  4      899.59O
5  5      204.68L
6  6      204.68L
7  7       13.59P
8  8       12.42R
9  9       13.59P
```