# Populate data from a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, statistics, data-analysis

I have a list with the following items

```
l = [11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 11.1, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 55.5]
```

Each item is a multiple of 11.1 and the length of the list is 8.
I would like to generate another list of 30 items with values 11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 55.5
present in the original list `l`.

I would like to know how to populate data from the list `l` to `l_new`.

Comment: Do you want to generate `l_new` at random with selected values?

Comment: Can you share an output example?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes, you are right. Or, is it possible to generate l_new such that `l` and `l_new` have the same distribution

Comment: @CarloZanocco I hope the above comment tries to answer your question partially

Comment: Can you tell me if the answer solved your problem?

Comment: @CarloZanocco Thank you. It almost solved my problem. But is it possible to check if `l` and `l_new` follow the same distribution pattern?

Comment: Take a look [here for the distributions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559470/what-do-all-the-distributions-available-in-scipy-stats-look-like/37559471#37559471)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module to do it:

```py
import random

l = [11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 11.1, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 55.5]

l_new = [random.choice(l) for _ in range(0, 30)]
print(l_new)

#OUTPUT:
#[11.1, 11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 22.2, 11.1, 33.3, 11.1, 55.5, 11.1, 33.3, 22.2, 55.5, 22.2, 22.2, 33.3, 11.1, 11.1, 33.3, 22.2, 33.3, 11.1, 11.1, 33.3, 22.2, 33.3, 33.3, 11.1, 33.3, 22.2]

l_new = random.choices(l, k=30)
print(l_new)

#OUTPUT:
#[11.1, 33.3, 33.3, 55.5, 33.3, 33.3, 55.5, 11.1, 22.2, 11.1, 55.5, 11.1, 11.1, 55.5, 22.2, 22.2, 22.2, 33.3, 11.1, 33.3, 55.5, 55.5, 33.3, 11.1, 11.1, 55.5, 22.2, 22.2, 11.1, 22.2]
```

The first solution `l_new = [random.choice(l) for _ in range(0, 30)]` use list comprehension and the [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) function that select one item from `l` for each iteration.

The second solution `l_new = random.choices(l, k=30)` just call the [`choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) function and let it generate the list, you have to specify the `k` that is the number of element to select.

---

There is another way that require the `numpy` module:

```py
import numpy

l = [11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 11.1, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 55.5]

l_new = list(numpy.random.choice(l, size=30))
print(l_new)

#OUTPUT:
#[11.1, 33.3, 11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 22.2, 22.2, 33.3, 55.5, 33.3, 22.2, 33.3, 22.2, 55.5, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 55.5, 33.3, 11.1, 11.1, 11.1, 55.5, 11.1, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 22.2, 33.3, 22.2]
```

The list is generated by [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

Comment: I would like to know if we can fix the seed while using `numpy.random.choice`. Thanks a lot for the solution posted.

Comment: This should do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52991726/5532710

Comment: `from numpy.random import MT19937
from numpy.random import RandomState, SeedSequence
rs = RandomState(MT19937(SeedSequence(123456789)))
# Later, you want to restart the stream
rs = RandomState(MT19937(SeedSequence(987654321)))` is provided [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html). I am not sure how to use this in the answer posted. Could you please help?

Comment: Can you create a new question regarding this please and explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64276987/how-to-fix-the-seed-while-using-random-choice