# How to fix the seed while using random.choice?

Tags: python-3.x, random

This is a follow up to my question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64185570/populate-data-from-a-list/64186490?noredirect=1#comment113661059_64186490)

```
import random

l = [11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 11.1, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 55.5]

l_new = random.choices(l, k=30)
print(l_new)
```

`random.choice` generates a new list using values from `l`. I would like to create the same output each time by fixing the seed of `random.choice`.

Suggestions will be really helpful.

Output obtained:
Run1:

```
[33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 55.5, 11.1, 11.1, 55.5, 22.2, 11.1, 33.3, 11.1, 55.5, 22.2, 33.3, 22.2, 22.2, 33.3, 55.5, 11.1, 11.1, 55.5, 11.1, 33.3, 11.1, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 33.3, 11.1]
```

Run2:

```
[22.2, 11.1, 33.3, 55.5, 33.3, 22.2, 33.3, 11.1, 22.2, 11.1, 11.1, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 33.3, 22.2, 11.1, 11.1, 55.5, 55.5, 33.3, 11.1, 55.5, 22.2, 33.3, 33.3, 55.5, 22.2, 22.2, 33.3]
```

Expected:

Run1:

```
[22.2, 11.1, 33.3, 55.5, 33.3, 22.2, 33.3, 11.1, 22.2, 11.1, 11.1, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 33.3, 22.2, 11.1, 11.1, 55.5, 55.5, 33.3, 11.1, 55.5, 22.2, 33.3, 33.3, 55.5, 22.2, 22.2, 33.3]
```

Run2:

```
[22.2, 11.1, 33.3, 55.5, 33.3, 22.2, 33.3, 11.1, 22.2, 11.1, 11.1, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 33.3, 22.2, 11.1, 11.1, 55.5, 55.5, 33.3, 11.1, 55.5, 22.2, 33.3, 33.3, 55.5, 22.2, 22.2, 33.3]
```

Comment: `random.seed(n)` should have the intended effect I think. If you add it before your code

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is? To set the random seed, there is literally a function called ``random.seed``. Did you use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`random.seed()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.seed)

```
import random

l = [11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 11.1, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 55.5]
random.seed(1)

l_new = random.choices(l, k=30)
print(l_new)
```

OUTPUT Run 1:

```
[55.5, 55.5, 11.1, 11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 11.1, 11.1, 33.3, 55.5, 55.5, 33.3, 11.1, 33.3, 11.1, 11.1, 11.1, 33.3, 11.1, 55.5, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 11.1]
```

OUTPUT Run 2:

```
[55.5, 55.5, 11.1, 11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 11.1, 11.1, 33.3, 55.5, 55.5, 33.3, 11.1, 33.3, 11.1, 11.1, 11.1, 33.3, 11.1, 55.5, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 11.1]
```

This code will always generate the same result each run.

---

In case you use numpy there is `numpy.random.seeed()`

```
import numpy

l = [11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 11.1, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 55.5]

numpy.random.seed(1)
l_new = list(numpy.random.choice(l, size=30))
print(l_new)
```

OUTPUT Run 1:

```
[33.3, 11.1, 33.3, 11.1, 55.5, 22.2, 11.1, 33.3, 55.5, 11.1, 11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 55.5, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 22.2, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 11.1, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2]
```

OUTPUT Run 2:

```
[33.3, 11.1, 33.3, 11.1, 55.5, 22.2, 11.1, 33.3, 55.5, 11.1, 11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 55.5, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 22.2, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 11.1, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 33.3, 22.2]
```