# Random seeding in open AI gym

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, random-seed, openai-gym

I have a question about seeding in open AI gym and utilizing it in custom environments.
Let's take the [lunar lander environment](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/box2d/lunar_lander.py) for example, the default seeding function is:

```
def seed(self, seed=None):
    self.np_random, seed = seeding.np_random(seed)
    return [seed]
```

And when generating they use:

```
height = self.np_random.uniform(0, H/2, size=(CHUNKS+1,) )
```

My question is, if I make a custom environment and use numpy or sci stats I would need to seed with `np.random.seed()` to get an effect. How should I use `self.np_random.`to seed in my custom environment? If I use `np.random.uniform(0,0.02)`? Should I use `self.np_random.uniform(0,0.02)` instead? What about sci-stats? How should I use it there if I use `scipy.stats.truncnorm.rvs()`? Any consequence if I just set `np.random.seed(seed)`?

I am using this workaround now: [Can I create a local numpy random seed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555991/can-i-create-a-local-numpy-random-seed)

Is there a better solution?